# Adminlte angular treeview menu not opening items

Tags: angular, treeview, adminlte

So, im working in a plataform and im using Angular and AdminLTE. After logging into the dashboard, my treeview menu doesnt work. Looks like it only works when i change li class to nav-item menu-open from the browser.
I'm not getting any errors in the console

Please help, im getting crazy with this.

I tried to init the treeview with ngOnInit nothing changed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.